# How do I securely store passwords?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, security, password

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Password Management Applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30907/password-management-applications)

How do I securely store passwords in Ubuntu? Are there any tools available for this?